# Not able to insert DATE type record into derby

Tags: java, mysql, derby

I am having a tough time to figure out how I can insert DATE type record in to derby database. I have created a table with column type `TIME_EXECUTED DATE NOT NULL`. Below is the query

```
public void addMetric(String provider, Date date) {
        try {


            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String inserTableSql = "INSERT INTO tableName"
                    + "(PROVIDER,TIME_EXECUTED) VALUES"
                    + "(?,?)";
            PreparedStatement p=conn.prepareStatement(inserTableSql);
            p.setString(1, provider);
            p.setDate(9, date);
            ResultSet rs=p.executeQuery();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is how I am passing date in the method

```
private static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());

    }
```

This is the error I am getting `ERROR 22007: The syntax of the string representation of a date/time value is incorrect.`

Any help will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: check `p.setDate(9, date);` Shouldn't that be `2` instead of `9` ?

Comment: Sorry my bad that was typo. it is actually 2. And same issue.

Comment: Did you try passing in a `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes I did

Comment: @user557657 Ah, sorry, didn't see the latter code, only saw the unqualified `Date` type on the parameter.

Comment: try setting it as a string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of a date.

Comment: @Sachin I do not understand? Where should I try setting ? here `p.setDate(9, date)` ?

Comment: Yes.. Just to try if the issue is with the database table or with prepared statement.. so, try something like `p.setString(2, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date))`